# List.Add reset on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I try to add dynamically items in a `List<>` class in asp.net. On Winforms it works but on ASP.NET it doesn't.
This is my code.

```
class artikuj
{
    public int artId { get; set; }
    public double sasia { get; set; }
}

List<artikuj> art = new List<artikuj>();

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        art.Add(new artikuj
        {
            artId = int.Parse(DropDownListArikujt.SelectedValue),
            sasia = double.Parse(tbSasia.Text)
        });

        Label1.Text = art.Count.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }

}
```

Every time I press the button the list resets and the new item is added.
Any idea why this error occurs? I tried and tried but no success. :/

Comment: All objects (or controls) are disposed at the end of the page's liefycle, so when the page is rendered as HTML and sent to the client. That's how HTTP works. Otherwise ASP.NET would have to store everything in memory. Consider that you have thousands of users and sites.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the first things that trip people over who are used to writing desktop apps and go over to creating web apps. It *looks* like all the coding should be the same, but the first thing you learn - ASP.NET is stateless.

That means that every time a new request comes in to your page, a new instance of the page is created, and along with it your instance-held list of items.

There are [many ways to maintain state between requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s(v=vs.100).aspx) with ASP.NET, but they are to expansive and broad to put into an answer. You could start by looking at [Getting started with ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/get-started)

Comment: To get around this, you can dump the generic list into the ViewState bag (caution, it can get large) to pass back and forth, or, save the contents of the list to a cookie.  Otherwise, the List will need to be created when it needs to be used

Comment: @Feuerwehrmann , ah did not know that. :/ What do you mean with "caution, it can get large" about viewstate?

Comment: @Feuerwehrmann , i thought about session of viewstate but i do not think this is a good choice.

Comment: Here are some options mentioned: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s(v=vs.100).aspx